# Duvida sobre registros em C

Tags: c

Olá estou com uma duvida nesse exercicio na ultima frase, esta pedindo para fazer uma lista mas n diz que é para colocar no registro mas estou colocando a lista dentro do registro para guardar mas n sei se isso que é para fazer.

> 1. Desenvolva um algoritmo para gerenciar alunos de um curso. É preciso armazenar informações sobre os alunos e sobre as disciplinas. Sobre disciplinas, é preciso armazenar uma lista das mesmas, contendo seu nome, nome do professor, carga horária (30 ou 60) e horário semanal. A lista de disciplinas a ser utilizada pode ser encontrada ao final deste documento, na seção “Recursos”. As mesmas não irão ser modificadas durante a execução do programa. 
>      Quanto aos horários, para simplificar, as aulas ocorrem apenas nos dias de semana e são organizadas em blocos de 2 horas. Uma disciplina pode possuir um ou dois blocos por semana. Cada dia da semana possui 4 blocos. O bloco 1 ocorre sempre às 8:00 e o bloco 2 ocorre as 10:00 da manhã. O bloco 3 ocorre as 13:00 e o bloco 4 as 15:00. Por exemplo, a disciplina de algoritmos ocorre às terças e quintas. No segundo bloco da terça e no terceiro da quinta. Consequentemente, algoritmos será ministrado as 10:00 de terça e as 13:00 de quinta. 
>      Quanto aos alunos, armazenar uma lista dos mesmos, para cada aluno deve conter: matricula, nome, sobrenome, email, lista de disciplinas matriculadas (apenas o semestre corrente) e grade horária (criada com base nos blocos explicados acima). 
>      Para as listas de alunos, disciplinas e disciplinas matriculadas do aluno, é preciso utilizar vetores. Para armazenar a grade horária do aluno, é necessário utilizar matrizes. Para cara aluno e disciplina, é necessário utilizar registros.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    struct diciplinas
    {

    int codigo;
    char nome[20];
    char professor[20];
    int c_Horaria;
    char h_Semanal[30]; 



    };

    struct registro
    {

    int matricula;
    char nome[20];
    char sobrenome[20];
    char email[20];
    int l_Diciplinas[5];

    };


void add_Aluno(struct registro al[3], struct diciplinas add_Dis[5]){
    char sairm;
    int dis,x,y=0,guarda[5];
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("---Voce selecionou adicionar aluno.---\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Lista de diciplinas\n");
                //mostra a lista das materias
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
        printf("Digite seu nome:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(al[x].nome);
        printf("Digite seu Sobrenome:");
        gets(al[x].sobrenome);
        strcat(al[x].nome,al[x].sobrenome);
        printf("Digite sua Matricula:");
        scanf("%d",&al[x].matricula);
        printf("Digite seu e-mail:");
        gets(al[x].email);
        printf("Digite O codigo das diciplinas que voce deseja se matricular\n");
        for(y=0; y<5; y++){
        scanf("%d",&al[x].l_Diciplinas);
}

        }   
    }






main(){

    struct diciplinas curso[5];
    struct registro alunos[3];
    int escolha;
    char grade[5][5];
    curso[0].codigo=122;
    strcpy(curso[0].nome,"Algoritimos");
    curso[0].c_Horaria=60;
    strcpy(curso[0].h_Semanal,"Segunda bloco 1 e terca bloco 2");

    curso[1].codigo=127;
    strcpy(curso[1].nome,"Estrutura de dados");
    curso[1].c_Horaria=60;
    strcpy(curso[1].h_Semanal,"terca bloco 3 e quarta bloco 4");

    curso[2].codigo=132;                                                //dados salvos
    strcpy(curso[2].nome,"Sistemas Operacionais A ");
    curso[2].c_Horaria=60;
    strcpy(curso[2].h_Semanal,"Terca bloco 3 e Quinta bloco 2");

    curso[3].codigo=143;
    strcpy(curso[3].nome,"Padroes de Projeto");
    curso[3].c_Horaria=30;
    strcpy(curso[3].h_Semanal,"Sexta bloco 2");

    curso[4].codigo=135;
    strcpy(curso[4].nome,"Banco de dados ll");
    curso[4].c_Horaria=60;
    strcpy(curso[4].h_Semanal,"Quarta bloco 3 e sexta bloco 2");

    grade[0][0]="Segunda";



    printf(" -----------------------\n");
    printf(" ------Bem Vindo!!------\n");
    printf(" -----------------------\n");
    printf("Escolha uma das opcoes abaixo\n");
    printf("1. Adicionar aluno\n");
    printf("2. Consultar aluno\n");
    scanf("%d",&escolha);
    if(escolha == 1){
        add_Aluno(alunos,curso);
      }else if(escolha == 2){

    }


}
```

Comment: Li todo o enunciado porem nao entendi o que quer dizer com utilizar registros. Alias eu nunca ouvi falar em registros em C. Unica coisa que eu vejo que tem alguma ligacao sao variaveis tipo [`register`](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~azeredo/cursoC/aulas/ca20.html#cA24). Sera que nao se refere a `struct` registro? Se for isso o seu titulo esta meio confuso, da a entender que registro seria uma capacidade da linguagem C.

Comment: Voce esta certo é struct por algum motivo chamam de registro aqui. Mas já consegui resolver o problema